# Checksum of a function in memory

Tags: c++, function, memory, checksum

I am making a kind of anti-hack thing for a program, and I want to be able to create a checksum of the bytes of a function to see if it has been modified. I know how to do a checksum, but how do I get how many bytes I should checksum? Is there a way to get the size of my function?

Comment: If you're making an anti-hack thing, how do you know your checksumming function hasn't been changed?

Comment: by doing this, you add one location that needs to be patched by the hacker. is that going to be worth the effort?

Comment: This could be done (on x86 anyway) by generating assembly code and adding symbols at the end of each function, but...  I wouldn't want to maintain it...  And then it would probably break if any form of the whole program optimization is applied because the functions would move around in memory.  What you want to do is hard and easy to work around :)

Comment: @JimR: you're assuming (incorrectly) that x86 compilers do not break up functions. I know at least one compiler that creates non-contiguous functions.

Comment: @MSalters: That's a new one on me, I did not know that.  What compiler would that be?

Comment: @JimR: since that comment, I've heard that there are actually two: MSVC and Sun's. Apparently both can split a function in hot (commonly used) and cold (rarely called) parts.

Answer (score 4):

Don't even try. You cannot assume that a function is contiguous in memory: it may have basicblocks with lower start addresses than its entrypoint; it may share trailing basicblocks with other functions; it may contain interspersed data or alignment bytes or it may disappear entirely, depending on the calling site (due to the compiler deciding to inline the function).

There is no way for your code to know the size of the generated function. Just think about it: the size is entirely dependent on what the compiler emits and that depends on all kinds of compiler settings and flags (think an optimizing, heavily inlined release build vs a debug build or using enhanced instruction sets like SSE vs not using them).

Also, as already indicated, such a checksum check is trivial to work around as a hacker - just another branch you have to invert.

And lastly, as an exercise for the curious and because potential malicious hackers will use it too, I'd recommend locking at your binary via the IDA Pro disassembler. This will make a lot of the problems with your intended anti-hack mitigation obvious...

If you really do want to continue down this path I'd recommend anti [reversing resources](http://dvlabs.tippingpoint.com/blog/2008/08/07/mindshare-anti-reversing-techniques) or running a post processing step on your code that
a) chains all of your functions together by inserting jumps connecting them which will never be taken. Hide the branches behind opaque predicates. This will make the disassembly hard to read/understand and will even break some disassemblers doing static flow analysis due to the resulting immense function size.
b) redirects all function calls through a single big branching function. This will have a performance impact on your code but it will also make the callgraph completely unusable/unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can use the length of the symbol pointing to the function in your executable (assuming you can get your hands on it), but it's not actually required to be right -- the system won't care, it just goes to the start of the function and runs until the function returns. You can try finding the start of the next function and assuming the functions are sequential (besides padding, but there's no reason not to just checksum that too), but that requires that you know which function comes after the one you want to checksum. Either way, you'd have to have the executable analyze itself in memory to find that part of the header

Answer (score 0):

Code is usually in read only memory so that it can't change.

But you could embed a checksum for a DLL so that just after it is loaded it validates its own image and aborts if the DLL disk image has been modified. But has that not already been done by the OS?

Comment: I'm guessing this is an attempt to protect a piece of software from an attacker with full root access to the machine.

Comment: Even with full root access the hardware stops you from modifying read only memory.

Comment: @Martin York, root access allows you to change memory page flags, you can make change it from r+e to r+w.

Comment: I imagine he's worried about end-users taking his binary and manually modifying it, not rogue processes messing with the executable in memory

Comment: @Michael Mroze, Question was about "a function in memory" that makes me think that this question related to functions in memory, not in binary image.

Comment: This is to add a layer of protection for people who would detour functions with something like Microsoft Detours. So there's no good way to do it?

Comment: @SamJam: Sure is. Run the program on your own computer, where you control what the user does and does not do. The moment the software is executed on another person's computer, he can do whatever he likes with it, as long as he has (or can get) root/admin access to the OS, which most users have.

Comment: @jalf You're right, the solution to all software security problems is simply don't let anybody use the software. Thanks for adding valuable content to this question.

Comment: @SamJam: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I wasn't joking, and it seems like it *was* valuable information in that it is directly applicable to your question, and apparently you weren't aware of it before. You're up against one fundamental fact: the user controls his own computer. He can, assuming he has the admin/root password, modify the memory of any process, attach a debugger and inspect or change data on the fly, or do whatever else he pleases. *There is no way around this*.

Comment: If you compute a checksum, the user just has to modify the result that is returned from your checksum function. If you mark your process' memore as read-only (which the program code is already), he can just hook into the process and set every memory page to read-write. He has control of his computer. He can do whatever he pleases. And if you don't trust him, you don't have many options other than keeping the software away from him. Run it in a controlled environment (your own computer, say), where you can trust the user.

Answer (score 0):

Standard doesn't allow to use function as an argument of the `sizeof` operator. So there is no portable way to  get size of the function body. Moreover a function shouldn't necessarily be placed in a continuous memory block. Parts of the several functions could be shuffled in one place (that is what VS do in the Release build).